# Does display:table disorient screen readers?

Tags: html, css, screen-readers

I've read that [tables can be a pain for screen readers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760732/why-are-table-based-sites-bad-for-screen-reader-users), and obviously we should strive to make our web-apps as accessible as possible. That being said, sometimes it's tempting to use `display:table` to get some desired effect.

Does applying `display:table` cause trouble for screen readers or is it the actual `table` element in the DOM that can cause problems?

Comment: The answer might be an opinion

Comment: I'll remove that last bit (which does seem like an opinion, you're right). Thanks, @Huangism.

Comment: This may be helpful - http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201110/using_displaytable_has_semantic_effects_in_some_screen_readers/

Comment: Oo! Good find, @Pav. I didn't know about the wide variance among readers.